# How to debug Safari randomly ignoring CSS changes?

Tags: css, safari

I'm having a PITA issue with a website.

The Safari mac browser (the desktop one, specifically, mobile safari appears to work) is randomly ignoring some of my CSS -- most notably the background color applied to the HTML element.  Refresh and it may -- or may not -- go away.  Even more perplexing, the browser clearly knows that style is there!  I'm using media queries to create a responsive site, and if you change the width enough to trigger a style sheet switch...  it suddenly comes back, and everything works properly.

How the heck can I debug this?  There's no error output in the console, the same data is getting sent every time (as far as I can tell...), it's not that one of the files is failing to be found (some of the CSS that is being applied is from the same stylesheet as the background...).

I'm at a total loss as to how to even begin debugging this one.

Edit:

If it's helpful, I just noticed that reader mode doesn't work on the refreshes the exhibit the broken behavior, even after the changing width trick fixes the background.

Edit:

This bug apparently also effects the mobile version, but instead of hitting the site-wide css, it's attacking my media-query based layout css.

Answer (score 2):

You could, assuming you have the developer menu enabled, check Develop -> Disable Caches. This sounds like a caching issue.

If you don't have the developer menu enabled, enable it with settings (cmd+,) -> advanced -> show Develop menu in menu bar.

Comment: Not a caching issue.  If it were, it A) wouldn't randomly turn on and off at refresh, and B) wouldn't effect people on their first visit, halfway through the development cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this in Safari 5.7.1 on Windows 7. It looks to me like Safari is actually ignoring commented out CSS.  I removed all the comments, and now Safari *seems* to be behaving.  But this is random for me as well, so I am not sure.